# Order of conjugacy class of an element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be of order $20$ and have a trivial Center. Let $x$ be an element of order $4$. What are the possible orbits if its conjugacy  class?

My friend gave me this problem during our walk to the theatre.  I am not able to solve this confidently I know the three Sylow theorems and the counting theorems and stabilizers and orbits.

My work:

Stabilizers and orbit will divide $20$ so the orbit of $x$ is $(1,2,4,5,10)$ it can’t be $1$ since the center is  trivial. Also the stabilizer must contain $(e,x^2,x^3,x)$ so it has order at least $4$. I know that orbits partition the group and the only element with orbit order  $1$Is the identity so $20=1+$ combinations of $(4,5,10,2)$

Are there other tricks to eliminate other possibilities?

I only know that it can be one of $(2,4,5)$

Comment: At one point you said the center is trivial and elsewhere you said it’s not!?

Comment: Sorry, the center is trivial

Comment: $H=\{g\in G,gxg^{-1}=x\}$ is a subgroup and it contains the order 4 cyclic group generated by $x$, then $\{ gxg^{-1},g\in G\}$ is in bijection with $G/H$.

Comment: @reuns thank you for your answer. I now understand why it contains the cyclic group generated by $x$ but I still can’t figure out the Bijection part of your answer (and what it implies).

Comment: $gxg^{-1}=yxy^{-1}$ iff $y^{-1}gxg^{-1}y = x$ iff $y^{-1}g\in H$ iff $y^{-1}gH=H$ iff $gH=yH$, thus the orbit has size $|G/H|=|G|/|H|$